# Customize create content page

Tags: nodes

I'm wondering if there's a way to customize the create content page (not the content display page), including recordering and repositioning things.

ATM it's "Title" on top, followed by "Body" on the bottom, followed by other fields like "Upload" and "Save".

Is there a way to customise the labels, reorder and repositon this page?

For example: To move "Upload" on top and in the middle, followed by "Title" and "Body" below it while changing the label of Body to "Description", and changing the caption of the "Save" button to "Submit"?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around for a long time and found that the very powerful [Display Suite module](https://drupal.org/project/ds) that has a great screencast series covering it [here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7E361A55994F1648) was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Firstly you need to read and understand the [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) documentation to render and rearranging field items.
To alter Title , Body, Save etc you will need to understand [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), it is used for altering a form and [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) is a smarter way to do the same as hook_form_alter.
There is a cool [hook_form_alter tutorial](http://blip.tv/mustardseed-media-hd/mustardseed-hd-53-5900123) hope will help you.